# Hadoop Map Reduce wordcount Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out

Tags: java, hadoop

I have installed and configure hadoop as single node using manul from following site.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#running-a-mapreduce-job

I have compiled wordcount example and run it but it takes long time and generate `Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.`

```
hduser@aptunix0043:/usr/local/hadoop/src$ hadoop jar WordCount.jar org/apache/hadoop/examples/WordCount input  ot

****hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/input
12/07/03 02:52:35 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/07/03 02:52:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201207030248_0002
12/07/03 02:52:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/07/03 02:52:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/07/03 03:21:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :attempt_201207030248_0002_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED 
Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.

12/07/03 03:21:47 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection timed out
12/07/03 03:22:08 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection timed out
 /user/hduser/input/*12/07/03 03:50:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :      attempt_201207030248_0002_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
12/07/03 03:50:22 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection timed out
12/07/03 03:50:43 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection timed out
12/07/03 04:18:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :  attempt_201207030248_0002_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
12/07/03 04:18:56 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection timed out
12/07/03 04:19:17 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection timed out
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201207030248_0002
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 23
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=4
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=12948
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting  after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=1
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed reduce tasks=1
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=16469
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=661744
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=288616
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=661630
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=267085
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=18040
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=12761
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=183209984
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=18040
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=1086716
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=1940
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage  (bytes)=162856960
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=393482240
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=109844
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=109844
12/07/03 04:47:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=114
```

Any Clue?

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the tasktracker? It contains additional information.

Comment: I am new to hadoop. So I don't know what may be creating this problem. can you  specify any term/phrases that I can look into the log file.

Comment: Open up a web browser and enter the following URL to get to your JobTracker: http://127.0.0.1:50030/jobtracker.jsp, from there you should be able to locate the failed job (search for the job id job_201207030248_0002), click on the hyperlink to view the job details, then click on the hyperlink which denotes the failed reducer tasks, then click on the logs link - finally paste the log into pastebin or your original question

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of people who search in internet and reach this page like me, you may hit 2 issues here

1. DNS Resolution - Make sure you use fully qualified domain name for each host when hadoop is installed
2. Firewall - Firewall might block the ports 50060,50030 and few more ports based on your hadoop distribution (7182,7180 for cloudera)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error before and it was caused by DNS issues. Are you running in a Linux based distro? if so make sure that all of your /etc/hosts are sync, in my case I used an alias for each node "slave1 192.168.1.23" etc... but that did not matched the box name so I had to change it, or you can just change your box name to match the one that correspond on "slaves" in the hadoop conf.